# Fortran code giving error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have taken this Fortran program from a book which basically runs a goodness to fit test for certain data and gives output. Code and its actual result/output are given as under:

```
real*4 x(50),xc(50,20),omega(50)
integer ir(50)
real*8 xx
c This code tests goodness of fit.
n=47
c The method of Bak, Nielsen, and Madsen is used.
data (x(i), i=1,47)/ 18, 22, 26, 16, 19, 21, 18, 22,
* 25, 31, 30, 34, 31, 25, 21, 24, 21, 28, 24, 26, 32,
* 33, 36, 39, 32, 33, 42, 44, 43, 48, 50, 56, 57, 59,
* 51, 49, 49, 57, 69, 72, 75, 76, 78, 73, 73, 75, 86/
do 999 icase=1,2
c Parameter icase =1 or 2 denotes SDE model 1 or 2.
xx=102038.
m=8
h=1.0
do 10 j=1,m+1
10 omega(j)=0.0
kk=4
akk=kk
h=h/akk
do 202 i=2,n
xs=x(i-1)
xe=x(i)
do 202 j=1,m
xk=xs
do 252 k=1,kk
call functs(icase,xk,f,g)
call random(xx,rand1,rand2)
252 xk=xk+h*f+sqrt(h)*g*rand1
xc(i,j)=xk
202 continue
do 402 i=2,n
irr=1
do 302 j=1,m
xe=x(i)
xcalc=xc(i,j)
if(xe.gt.xcalc) irr=irr+1
302 continue
402 ir(i)=irr
do 502 i=2,n
irr=ir(i)
omega(irr)=omega(irr)+1.0
502 continue
chi2=0.0
an=n
am=m
hlp=(an-1.0)/(am+1.0)
do 602 j=1,m+1
602 chi2=chi2+(omega(j)-hlp)**2/hlp
write(6,100) icase,chi2
100 format(5x,i7,5x,f9.2)
999 continue
stop
end
subroutine functs(icase,x,f,g)
th1=3510.0
th2=13500.0
f=th1/(x*x)
g=th2/(x*x)
if(icase.eq.1) goto 17
th1=.0361
th2=.6090
f=th1*x
g=sqrt(th2*x)
17 continue
return
end
subroutine random(xx,rand1,rand2)
real*8 xx,a,b,d,rng(2)
a=16807.
ib=2147483647
b=ib
do 55 i=1,2
id=a*xx/b
d=id
xx=a*xx-d*b
55 rng(i)=xx/b
pi=3.141592654
u1=rng(1)
u2=rng(2)
hlp=sqrt(-2.0*alog(u1))
rand1=hlp*cos(pi*2.0*u2)
rand2=hlp*sin(pi*2.0*u2)
return
end
```

Output of this program is:

```
1 18.57
2 4.09
```

However, even after using many online Fortran compilers i am not  getting these results. It is giving errors like non standard type declaration etc.

I need help to get the same output as mentioned above.

Comment: Please give the exact errors, the lines they occur on, and show what you've don't to try and solve it.

Comment: Please use some indentation, spaces and empty lines to make your code readable. Seriusly, it is horrible. And tell us rhe exact error messages you get and the compiler command that created those messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is a written using the (old) Fortran 77 style with the addition of some common extensions. Since it uses the so called fixed-form the columns used by the source code are crucial to have a correct code. In particular for the case:

- comments are defined by c character at the first column
- continuation lines are defined by * at the sixth column
- labels must use the first 5 columns
- regular code must use 7-72 column range

Properly indenting your code allows to have it running on both GNU gfortran (tested using v.4.8.2) and Intel ifort (tested using version 15.0.2). To inform the compiler that you want to adopt the fixed-form for most compilers you have just to use .f extension for the source file. Otherwise you have suitable compilers options. For gfortran, compile specifying -ffixed-form. to  The (minimally) indented code is provided below.

```
      real*4 x(50),xc(50,20),omega(50)
      integer ir(50)
      real*8 xx
c This code tests goodness of fit.
      n=47
c The method of Bak, Nielsen, and Madsen is used.
      data (x(i), i=1,47)/ 18, 22, 26, 16, 19, 21, 18, 22,
     * 25, 31, 30, 34, 31, 25, 21, 24, 21, 28, 24, 26, 32,
     * 33, 36, 39, 32, 33, 42, 44, 43, 48, 50, 56, 57, 59,
     * 51, 49, 49, 57, 69, 72, 75, 76, 78, 73, 73, 75, 86/
      do 999 icase=1,2
c Parameter icase =1 or 2 denotes SDE model 1 or 2.
      xx=102038.
      m=8
      h=1.0
      do 10 j=1,m+1
10    omega(j)=0.0
      kk=4
      akk=kk
      h=h/akk
      do 202 i=2,n
      xs=x(i-1)
      xe=x(i)
      do 202 j=1,m
      xk=xs
      do 252 k=1,kk
      call functs(icase,xk,f,g)
      call random(xx,rand1,rand2)
252   xk=xk+h*f+sqrt(h)*g*rand1
      xc(i,j)=xk
202   continue
      do 402 i=2,n
      irr=1
      do 302 j=1,m
      xe=x(i)
      xcalc=xc(i,j)
      if(xe.gt.xcalc) irr=irr+1
302   continue
402   ir(i)=irr
      do 502 i=2,n
      irr=ir(i)
      omega(irr)=omega(irr)+1.0
502   continue
      chi2=0.0
      an=n
      am=m
      hlp=(an-1.0)/(am+1.0)
      do 602 j=1,m+1
602   chi2=chi2+(omega(j)-hlp)**2/hlp
      write(6,100) icase,chi2
100   format(5x,i7,5x,f9.2)
999   continue
      stop
      end
      subroutine functs(icase,x,f,g)
      th1=3510.0
      th2=13500.0
      f=th1/(x*x)
      g=th2/(x*x)
      if(icase.eq.1) goto 17
      th1=.0361
      th2=.6090
      f=th1*x
      g=sqrt(th2*x)
17    continue
      return
      end
      subroutine random(xx,rand1,rand2)
      real*8 xx,a,b,d,rng(2)
      a=16807.
      ib=2147483647
      b=ib
      do 55 i=1,2
      id=a*xx/b
      d=id
      xx=a*xx-d*b
55    rng(i)=xx/b
      pi=3.141592654
      u1=rng(1)
      u2=rng(2)
      hlp=sqrt(-2.0*alog(u1))
      rand1=hlp*cos(pi*2.0*u2)
      rand2=hlp*sin(pi*2.0*u2)
      return
      end
```

If you want to compile using an online resource be sure you properly copy-paste the code (with the right indentation) and use the option for the fixed form. For example using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php in the shell below compile typing:  `gfortran -ffixed-form *.f95 -o main`.

Since Fortran 77 style is quite old now, if you are starting a new code I personally suggest to move to free-form source code and to use more recent Fortran features. A possible rewrite of the code using a modern style is given below:

```
module my_kinds
    integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(9)
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(18)
end module my_kinds

program test_from_book
    use my_kinds
    real(sp) :: x(50),xc(50,20),omega(50)
    integer  :: ir(50)
    real(dp) :: xx
    ! This code tests goodness of fit.
    n=47
    ! The method of Bak, Nielsen, and Madsen is used.
    x = [ 18, 22, 26, 16, 19, 21, 18, 22, &
          25, 31, 30, 34, 31, 25, 21, 24, 21, 28, 24, 26, 32, &
          33, 36, 39, 32, 33, 42, 44, 43, 48, 50, 56, 57, 59, &
          51, 49, 49, 57, 69, 72, 75, 76, 78, 73, 73, 75, 86, &
          0 ,  0,  0]
    loop_999: do icase=1,2
        ! Parameter icase =1 or 2 denotes SDE model 1 or 2.
        xx=102038.
        m=8
        h=1.0
        do j=1,m+1
            omega(j)=0.0
        enddo
        kk=4
        akk=kk
        h=h/akk
        loop_202: do i=2,n
            xs=x(i-1)
            xe=x(i)
            do j=1,m
                xk=xs
                do k=1,kk
                    call functs(icase,xk,f,g)
                    call random(xx,rand1,rand2)
                    xk=xk+h*f+sqrt(h)*g*rand1
                enddo
                xc(i,j)=xk
            enddo
        enddo loop_202
        loop_402: do i=2,n
            irr=1
            do j=1,m
                xe=x(i)
                xcalc=xc(i,j)
                if(xe.gt.xcalc) irr=irr+1
            enddo
            ir(i)=irr
        enddo loop_402
        do i=2,n
            irr=ir(i)
            omega(irr)=omega(irr)+1.0
        enddo
        chi2=0.0
        an=n
        am=m
        hlp=(an-1.0)/(am+1.0)
        do j=1,m+1
            chi2=chi2+(omega(j)-hlp)**2/hlp
        enddo
        write(6,100) icase,chi2
        100 format(5x,i7,5x,f9.2)
    enddo loop_999
    stop
end

subroutine functs(icase,x,f,g)
    th1=3510.0
    th2=13500.0
    f=th1/(x*x)
    g=th2/(x*x)
    if(icase.ne.1) then
        th1=.0361
        th2=.6090
        f=th1*x
        g=sqrt(th2*x)
    endif
end

subroutine random(xx,rand1,rand2)
    use my_kinds
    real(dp) :: xx,a,b,d,rng(2)
    a=16807.
    ib=2147483647
    b=ib
    do i=1,2
        id=a*xx/b
        d=id
        xx=a*xx-d*b
        rng(i)=xx/b
    enddo
    pi=3.141592654
    u1=rng(1)
    u2=rng(2)
    hlp=sqrt(-2.0*alog(u1))
    rand1=hlp*cos(pi*2.0*u2)
    rand2=hlp*sin(pi*2.0*u2)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the modern style code worked well!